# Colouring of datapoint with ggplot2 and RColorBrewer

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have got a `df` with over 400 datapoints and want to colour those accourding to the `RColorBrewer` package with the `palette = "Blues"`.

I plotted my data and even expanded the color input maximum of the `palette` to the length of my data points to avoid getting "Error messages" (see below), but the colors in the plot aren't changing (only a black line).

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the
>   same as the data (427): fill

I've created a `dummy df` to make my problem reproducible:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer) 

color = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "Blues")))(300)

df = (curve(3*x^2 + x, from=1, to=10, n=300, xlab="xvalue", ylab="yvalue", 
         col="blue", lwd=2, main="Plot of (3x^2 + x)"))
dfx = matrix(data = df$x, ncol = 1)
dfy = matrix(data = df$y, ncol = 1)
dfa = cbind(dfx,dfy)

DF = ggplot(dfa, aes(x = dfx, y = dfy)) +
      geom_point(fill = color)
```

I expect the curve to change into a light blue at the start (1,4) with an increase in darkness till the end (dark blue at the end (10,310)).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exDF <- data.frame(dataX = seq(1, 10, .1),
                   dataY = sapply(seq(1, 10, .1), function(x) 3*x^2 + x))

exDFcolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))(nrow(exDF))

ggplot(exDF, aes(dataX, dataY)) +
  geom_line(size = 2, color = exDFcolors)
```

[image]

Comment: The function and its combining was just to create the `df`. I am using different data to make my plots. Can you give me an example on how it would look like if you would edit my "`DF`" code? How your colouring looks exactly as I wanted it, so thanks for that already!

Answer (score 2):

```
color_seq = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "Blues"))(300)

df = (curve(3*x^2 + x, from=1, to=10, n=300, xlab="xvalue", ylab="yvalue", 
            col="blue", lwd=2, main="Plot of (3x^2 + x)"))
dfx = matrix(data = df$x, ncol = 1)
dfy = matrix(data = df$y, ncol = 1)
dfa = as.data.frame(cbind(dfx , dfy, color_seq), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfa$V1 <- as.numeric(dfa$V1)  ## convert both to numeric so the scale is continous
dfa$V2 <- as.numeric(dfa$V2)

ggplot(dfa, aes(x = V1, y = V2, color = color_seq)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```